# Azure Functions : Local Development : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Calculated MD5 does not match existing property

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am writing some Azure functions locally which I build into a Docker Image.

All has been working fine up until now when one fails to run locally. (Builds, but doesn't run).  It is a Timer function (there are 3 timers and 2 http which all work)

It gives an error saying:

> [31/03/2020 07:52:36] The listener for function 'IndexSites' was unable to start.
>   [31/03/2020 07:52:36] The listener for function 'IndexSites' was unable to start. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Calculated MD5 does not match existing property.

I am not using any files, and this is running locally.

I have tried to clear the Azure Storage emulator but not sure what that is being used for (Only talking to Mongo).

Comment: Get this error without trigger it?

Comment: Its a timer trigger

Comment: Could you please post your configuration that you are using to connect to your local storage emulator?

Comment: Where is that? I have not changed anything from default